# Is it possible to run 2 firefox instances one in safe mode and one not

Tags: firefox

I love firebug for helping debug my web apps, as well as seeing how others have implemented there sites.  However firebug hinders memory leak testing.

I've just found that FireFox can be launched in safemode which disables all addons, which is great for memory usage testing however once firefix is launched (either samemode or not) all subsequent firefox launches (they all appear in task manager as 1 firefox instance) will use the mode of the first one.

I'd like to leave one in same mode testing some apps for leaks and use another with firebug to develop.

I've tried making a copy of the FireFix.exe and even copying the whole firefox directory but it still launches as one application.

I could always use VirtualBox to create a full virtual PC for this testing but that seams like a large overhead.

**Edit**

I have just tried the -no-remote switch but it just comes up with "firefox is already running .... you must first close the existing Firefox process.... "

Comment: Note that safe mode also disables graphics hardware acceleration and the JS JITs, so the memory behavior will be quite different from normal mode...  That said, if you're looking for leaks in your JS code the behavior should be similar enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First close all your Firefox instances. With all instances closed, run firefox via the "Run..." dialog on windows, typing "firefox -p". It will open with the profile manager, where you can create multiple profiles with different configurations.

After creating your profiles, just run you "main" browser using "firefox -p" and select your "main" profile. To open another instance using a different profile, run Firefox using "firefox -no-remote -p" and it will prompt the profile manager again, so you can choose a different profile.

Comment: Using -no-remote without using -p it won't open, because the first profile is already running. You need to create another profile to run another instance.